# PHP : Post > Diaplay > Wait > Redirect

Tags: php, post, redirect

i post something from a form and the form's action is a page `perform.php`

when i go to `perform.php`

```
<?php
$g = $_POST['my'];
sleep(3);
echo ("sdfsdfdsfdsfdsfdsf");
// a lot of other PHP & DB related code

//after a lot of code last line is
header("Location: source.php");
?>
```

what it does is that it does everything that needs to be done and i see loading of page and after that loading i don't actually get to see `perform.php` for which the code i have given... and i am directed to `source.php`

what i was intending is from the form page i go to `perform.php` and there i will show some text and and after 3 seconds it will be redirected to `source.php` but that failed...

HOW TO DO IT

Comment: Don't do it this way. I don't know what is your certain task but I can assure you that nobody is doing things that way.

Comment: @col. Sharpnel: if you read the question.. you'd come to know what is my task... and why the down vote... this question is here because i am asking how to do it... if you do know this is not the way its done then post an answer saying how.... don't go around doing reckless posting and voting... and don't comment if you don't know what my task is.. maybe you are just too dumb to understand the question... you brain surgeon

Comment: Oh, I can't believe a downvote can hurt that much. Please accept my sincere condolences

Comment: its not the downvote.. its your attitude "I don't know what is your certain task but I can assure you that nobody is doing things that way." ... If you don't know what my certain task is then how do you what the right way or whats everybody way of doing it... choose your words wisely....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="3;url=http://somewhere.com/source.php">
```

Don't do it via PHP. Why?

What PHP currently does:

Request comes in -> PHP does some stuff, waits 3 seconds WITHOUT SENDING ANY DATA TO THE BROWSER -> PHP tells browser to go to source.php (without showing anything).

What it should do:

Request comes in -> PHP returns HTML and includes tag to tell browser to redirect after 3 secs.